# check the id of tag in xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have xml file like below, and I want to check if the id in specific tag equal to it's value in java

```
<pages id="TestData">
<CountryName>UAE</CountryName>
<Username>ismail990</Username>
<Password>ismail990</Password>
<Facebook_Username>ismail@123123.com</Facebook_Username>
<Facebook_Password>123123123</Facebook_Password>
<Twitter_Username>ismail@123123.com</Twitter_Username>
<Twitter_Password>12312123</Twitter_Password>
</pages>
```

so I need to check the tag first (in my case is pages), then check if the id of pages tag equal to value (in my case is TestData)

Comment: You should try looking into JDOM

Comment: thanks but I don't want libraries
I need native code

Comment: see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#CCHIBFIA)

Comment: @IsmailAhmad libraries are code... You need an xml parser that provides you with a DOM or at least XPath. The ugly answer is regex and/or substring...